# Is really Set.contains is much faster than Array.contains? And why?

Tags: arrays, swift, performance, optimization, set

Many people tell that Set.contains performance overcomes Array.contains performance, for example: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swift/why-is-contains-so-much-faster-with-sets-compared-to-arrays/13421

But what's behind if its true?

In case of set, first, hash value is calculated. Then program iterates over low-level unsorted array (not a swift array, but something like values aligned together in memory) of unique hashes, until it is matched.

In case of array, the program just iterates over array until it is matched.

So I guess that Set.contains overcomes Array.contains in performance only then Array contains lots of duplicates.

But if Array consists of unique values, its .contains method should overcome Set's one.

Also, comparing hashed should take much more resources than comparing Integers or other simple values (I know that Integer is Struct in swift, but anyway, it should finally come to compare 8 bytes in memory in case of iOS while hash should take much more bytes in memory).

Can you please explain if I'm correct or not?

Also, Set behind the scene may use some tricks to improve searching performance like using sorted low-level arrays and binary searching which would be much faster that linear search...

Thank you.

Comment: The set might not be a linear search - it could be a tree. After the hash, the first check could come up empty. Just guessing. You'll have to read the source to see what the two are doing.

Comment: @aMike The elements of a set have to conform to `Hashable`. This tells us the underlying implementation is a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). This is where the `O(1)` claim comes from.

Comment: You're thinking of a `Set` as if it's just a buffer being linearly searched similar to an `Array`, where the value being matched is the hash of the item, rather than the item itself. But that's not the case. The hash value is used to quickly narrow in on a smaller region where the element will be, akin to going directly to the dairy isle when searching for milk, so that you don't have to waste time for searching for milk in the produce isle, cheese isle, boxed goods isle, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then program iterates over low-level unsorted array

No, a `Set` is more like a dictionary with the hash value as `key` and the real value as `value`. `contains` called on a `Set` has `O(1)` complexity, this means it takes always the same time to get the value regardless of the size of the `Set`.

In contrast an `Array` does iterate over the items, the complexity of `contains` is `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the array.

Bottom line: A `Set` is much more performant with regard to `contains`.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation, Vadian. But there's additional question - O(1) means just constant time, not depending on set size (in first approximation - I've read that all hash table may be fully recalculated to increase its size for fast 'growing' sets). Okay, I definitely understood that Set should be definitely used if N is a big number. But does it worth using it in case if N is small (for example N < 50). May it be worth using Array in this case because it uses less memory than hash table and it may be really faster for small values of N? Or I just should n't care for such cases?

Comment: If the order doesn't matter and the collection contains unique values use always `Set`, otherwise `Array`.